# Fetch API file upload failing while XHR works

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I'm trying to asynchronously upload a file via javascript in the background. I'm updating our library to use fetch instead of XHR. The XHR request works correctly and the network tab shows the expected response which is currently just a var_dump($_FILES) and a var_dump($_POST).

When I make the same call with fetch for some reason the PHP stops running on the session creation.
I've isolated it down to the line:

`$session = new Session;`

Here is a cleaned up version of the XHR which returns both of those PHP arrays populated correctly

```
    var request = {},
        url = "../../lib/upload.php",
        formData = new FormData;

    formData.append(
      "PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS", phpSessionKey // upload session key var
    );

    formData.append(
      "uploaded_file", this.file.baseFile // file object from an upload input
    );

    formData.append(
      "pageid", 1234
    );

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
         console.log(responseText);
      }
    }
    request.send(formData);
```

Here is the comparable fetch, mind you I've looked at headers and everything else which all seem to be identical but I can not figure out why the fetch version exits on that session creation line.

```
    let formData = new FormData(),
        phpSessionKey = Uploader.pageid + "_" + this.file.name,
        that = this;

    formData.append(
      "PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS", phpSessionKey
    );

    formData.append(
      "uploaded_file", this.file.baseFile
    );

    formData.append(
      "pageid", Uploader.pageid
    );

    fetch('../lib/upload.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    });
```

This fetch in the network tab returns nothing and by going in and comment then uncommenting lines I've narrowed the issue down to the session creation line in upload.php. I'm honestly just confused about why this is happening at this point, trying to bring out JS standards up has been pretty smooth sailing until now.

**EDIT**

Here is the session class in PHP:

```
class Session {
    private $user_id;
    private $last_login;
    private $database;
    public $user;
    public $username;

    public const MAX_LOGIN_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24; // 1 day

    // Constructor which attaches pseudo magic methods to php sessions
    public function __construct()
    {
      session_set_save_handler(
        array($this, '_open'),
        array($this, '_close'),
        array($this, '_read'),
        array($this, '_write'),
        array($this, '_destroy'),
        array($this, '_clean')
      );

      session_start();
      $this->check_stored_login();
    }

    public function _open()
    {

      if ($session_db = db_connect(DB_DEV)) {
        $this->database = $session_db;
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

    public function _close()
    {
      // print "Session closed.\n";

      return $this->database->close();
    }

    public function _read($id)
    {
      $id = $this->database->escape_string($id);

      // print "Session read.\n";
      // print "Sess_ID: $id\n";

      $sql = "SELECT data
              FROM sessions
              WHERE id = '{$id}'";

      if ($result = $this->database->query($sql)) {
        if ($result->num_rows) {
          $record = $result->fetch_assoc();

          return $record['data'];
        }
      }

      return '';
    }

    public function _write($id, $data)
    {
      $access = time();

      $id = $this->database->escape_string($id);
      $access = $this->database->escape_string($access);
      $data = $this->database->escape_string($data);
      // print "Session value written.\n";
      // print "Sess_ID: $id\n";
      // print "Data: $data\n\n";

      $sql = "REPLACE
              INTO sessions (`id`, `access`, `data`)
              VALUES ('{$id}', '{$access}', '{$data}')";

      $this->database->query($sql);

      return true;
    }

    public function _destroy($id)
    {
      $id = $this->database->escape_string($id);

      // print "Session destroy called.\n";

      $sql = "DELETE
              FROM sessions
              WHERE id='{$id}'";

      return $this->database->query($sql);
    }

    public function _clean($max)
    {
      $old = $time() - $max;
      $this->database->escape_string($old);

      $sql = "DELETE
              FROM sessions
              WHERE access < '{$old}'";

      return $this->database->query($sql);
    }

    public function login($user)
    {
      if ($user) {
        // prevent session fixation attacks
        session_regenerate_id();
        $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id = $user->id;
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = $user->first_name;
        $this->last_login = $_SESSION['last_login'] = time();
        $this->user = $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['search_text'] = '';
        $_SESSION['search_product_id'] = '';
        $args["last_login"] = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
        $user->merge_attributes($args);
        $user->save();
      }
    }

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
      if (!isset($this->user_id) || !$this->last_login_recent()) {
        redirect_to(url_for('/index.php?logout'));
      }

      return true;
    }

    public function logout()
    {
      unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
      unset($_SESSION['username']);
      unset($_SESSION['last_login']);
      unset($_SESSION['user']);
      unset($this->user_id);
      unset($this->username);
      unset($this->last_login);
      unset($this->user);
      session_destroy();

      return true;
    }

    private function check_stored_login()
    {
      if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $this->last_login = $_SESSION['last_login'];
        $this->user = $_SESSION['user'];
      }
    }

    private function last_login_recent()
    {
      if (!isset($this->last_login)) {
        return false;
      } elseif ($this->last_login + self::MAX_LOGIN_AGE < time()) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    public function message($msg = '')
    {
      if (!empty($msg)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;
      } else {
        return $_SESSION['message'];
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: You may need to provide a bit more on the PHP code about what the class `Session` does for its construct. Also, have you enabled ALL error reporting out of the php code, so you can get more of a response in the js call?

Comment: Added the Session PHP class assumed it shouldn't be needed if the POST's were identical which was obviously not wise. Going to start commenting out pieces of the constructor now to see if I can locate the point of failure in the class.

Also error reporting is set to all and it's giving me nothing.

Comment: After further testing it appears the fetch version exits on calling session_start();

Comment: Try to add `credentials: 'same-origin',` into your `fetch` parameters. However if its exiting early on `session_start();` ... no idea whats going on there, as I've never had a php script exit on that function.

Comment: So I tried this (didn't work) as well as going line by line and narrowing it down more, it seems to occur between session read and session write. If I put an exit right before the return of _read it prints out the same things for both the XHR and Fetch. If I put it on the first line of _write the XHR returns text and the fetch returns nothing. I tried printing on the _clean method to see if perhaps that was happening in between but got nothing. Any ideas of what might be occurring between those two?